# jQuery - correct input min / max with delay on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code:

```
var $this = $(this);
var val = $this.val();
var max = $this.attr("max");
var min = $this.attr("min");

if (max > 0 && val > max){
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.val(max);
}
else if (min > 0 && val < min)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $this.val(min);
}
```

The problem is for instance when `min/max` are `70/250` and the user try to type  `200` it gets instantly corrected from `2` to `70` -_- so I need timeout/delay on `keyup` so I tried:

```
var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();


$("input").keyup(function(e) {
    delay(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var val = $this.val();
        var max = $this.attr("max");
        var min = $this.attr("min");

        if (max > 0 && val > max){
            e.preventDefault();
            $this.val(max);
        }
        else if (min > 0 && val < min)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $this.val(min);
        }
    }, 1000 );
});
```

But now the correction isn't getting executed. How to do it right? Does anyone also have a btter idea to solve the "typing 200 without getting instantly corrected" problem?

Comment: maybe onchange instead of keyup? so you will change the users input only after he finished 'inputing' it

Comment: Nice I think I will go with that thanks :D But do you still have solution for keyup delay? I can't afford having more "unsolved" questions or else I won't be able to ask any any more xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Jquery focusout function.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusout.asp

This will check when the user moves to another field or input section and will then perform your validation. No need then for timers or delays.

```
$("input").focusout(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var val = $this.val();
        var max = $this.attr("max");
        var min = $this.attr("min");

        if (max > 0 && val > max){
            e.preventDefault();
            $this.val(max);
        }
        else if (min > 0 && val < min)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $this.val(min);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called 'debouncing': you may want to tinker with this solution:
https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: I'll take a look at that